# Property target does exist on object

Tags: angular, typescript

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        const searchSource = document.getElementById("search-box");      
        const inputStream = fromEvent(searchSource, "input");
        inputStream
            .pipe(
            map(event => (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value.trim()),
                debounceTime(500),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
        )
            .subscribe(() => {
                let updatedValue = encodeURI((searchSource as HTMLInputElement).value);

                if (updatedValue.length >= 2) {
                    this.listSearchResults(updatedValue);
                    this.showProgressbar = true;
                } else {
                    this.showDropDown = false;
                    this.noMatchesFound = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

TypeScript in Angular show error "Property target does exist on object" while trying to access target on event in the above code. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify type on event as `KeyboardEvent` / `MouseEvent`/ union of both, that will satisfy typings of `typescript`

```
map((event: KeyboardEvent|MouseEvent) => (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value.trim()),
```

---

Rather I would recommend you to use `#templateVariable` on element in this case, and use `@ViewChild` decorator to hold on that `DOM`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `document.getElementById` in `Angular` it can be done by `formControl` easily.

**HTML**

```
<input placeholder="Enter a value" [formControl]="searchCtrl"/>
```

**TS**

```
searchCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();

this.searchCtrl.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(500)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(val => {
        // Do whatever you want
    });
```